# How To Create Comments Section for App

Tags: android, adapter

I am looking to add a comments feature to my application.

Very high level, I was wondering what the best approach would be for layout purposes. My initial inclination is to create a view, which will represent each individual comment, and then use an adapter to add a view each time a new comment is added by an app user.

I wanted to hear of any thoughts on this process and whether or not there are other recommendations (i.e. libraries). Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out

- [Socialize SDK](http://getsocialize.com)
- Disqus android SDK

or implement your own solution